# Proper way to remove and add new html with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, append

I have two div elements inside another. At times, from user interactivity, these two items are removed, and two new elements are placed.

Is it proper to remove the existing elements first? Or just overwrite the html? Or does it even matter?

```
$('#item1').remove();
$('#item2').remove();
$('#itemWindow').append(newItem1);
$('#itemWindow').append(newItem2);
```

Or simply

```
$('#itemWindow').html(newItem1);
$('#itemWindow').append(newItem2);
```

One is less code, but should the item be removed instead? The items do not have any listeners, but if they did does that make a difference?

I'm an ActionScript developer diving into JS and jQuery. In AS, if any listeners exist, it's proper to remove the item first to sever any ties to the object, for proper memory collection. Are these rules the same with JS and jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the answer in regards to the listeners will depend on if you will want to reuse the listener...

Comment: If you view the jQuery source code, you will notice that html() method works like > this.empty().append( value ). Your are complicating where you dont need to ;-) Use to shorter code, like> $('#itemWindow').html(newItem1).append(newItem2);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have no difference. So you can go ahead and use the second method. as when you use this

```
$('#itemWindow').html(newItem1);
```

`$('#item1')` and  `$('#item2')` will be replaced. So you can skip removing those manually.

As @glavić mentioned in comment if you look at the definition of `html` method in jQuery source here  https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L213
You will find out at the end it has these lines

```
 if ( elem ) {
    this.empty().append( value );
 }
```

Where in this case `elem` is true. So the element will be `emptied` and then new element will be `appended`.

And if they had listeners then you have to bind listeners in a way so it works with dynamically added elements  like using [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on)

Answer (score 0):

$('#item1').remove(); will remove the element with id item1

$('#item1').html(newItem1); will set the html within the element with id item1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be specific about what you are actually removing, say in the case that you have one element that needs to be removed, but not the other, then I recommend the first method. If you are simply going to be replacing everything every time, then feel free to use either or, the only issue then is what is more readable for you.

Answer (score 0):

if item has any listener then first method is more appropriate. `.remove()` removes items itself and all bound event. if item is removed but not event, error may occur in future. but if no bounded event, second method can be used - coz less code.